# How to use hyphen to form new adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation

Writing a chemistry paper I need to form an adjective for the following concept: TiO2 rich in oxygen vacancies.

Is this the proper formation for an adjective intended to mean that?:

Oxygen-vacancy-rich TiO2

Are the two hyphens correct? Or do I only need the first one?

thank you

Comment: Your hyphenation is correct, but to a non-chemist, "vacancy-rich" seems something of an oxymoron.  We normally use the word "rich" to describe the abundant *presence* of something. Nitrogen-rich, for example, makes much better intuitive sense than vacancy-rich.

Comment: Yes, two hyphens are correct. One can be replaced with an en dash depending on the style guide you adhere to. No, only one hyphen and a space would be wrong. But the real question here is: why do you need to form an adjective? Here's ten roubles saying that you do not, as a matter of fact, need to form an adjective. (And here's another ten saying that chemists have long come up with a dedicated adjective for "vacancy-rich", and possibly even with a dedicated one for "oxygen-vacancy-rich".)

Comment: The adjectival *oxygen-vacant TiO2* seems to be used. You could say "highly oxygen-vacant TiO2".

Comment: Thank you all of you. I might use then "highly oxygen-vacant TiO2", in order not to get an oxymoron and make it clearer to the reader.

Comment: If there were an oxymoron as @TimRomano suggests, then "highly [something]-vacant" would be jsut as oxymoronic. I don't think there is though, a vacancy is an identifiable "thing" (albeit one defined by absense) even in general use. In chemistry, even more so.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: I don't really disagree, but "{noun}-rich" seems worse to me than "highly {noun}-vacant", (when the noun refers to something that is missing rather than abundant).

Comment: Yeah, the *highly* form is the more euphonious, either way.

Comment: The presence of vacancies at sites normally occupied by a particular element in a material is a rather specific fact about it. Sticking to a form which mentions the vacancies explicitly is probably a good idea. Two alternatives: *rich in oxygen vacancies*, *a high density of oxygen vacancies*.